# Error while opening Intellij IDEA due to an already running process

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to open the Intellij IDEA on Mac, but it is showing the following error:

> Cannot connect to already running IDE instance.

> Exception: Process 464 is still

I was able to open Intellij perfectly some time back, but now suddenly this error has popped up out of nowhere.

Comment: Please try the workaround described here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-330531.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Actually I am a beginner , and I am not understanding how to exactly do the 2 point mentioned there also like how to kill the process just know how to do the force quite which I already tried , and also I am using a mac

Comment: `sudo killall -9 idea`, `.lock` file is in the Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory, I'm sure you can find and delete it.

Comment: I faced this problem today, did a `ps -ef | grep 481 ` (for me the error was - `Cannot connect to already running IDE instance.
Exception: Process 481 is still running`) and it showed notes, I closed notes and then restarted intellij it started working.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to remove the *.lock* file in your configuration. It's in the *config* folder. The examples are for [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2023.2.

Linux:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2
```

Windows:

```
C:\Users\JohnS\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2
```

macOS:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2
```

There can be multiple versions of your program in the JetBrains folder, such as IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2. You need the latest.

Delete the *.lock* file and run the program; everything should work. At least it helped me.

---

On [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems (Linux and macOS) you can look for the location for the `.lock` file using:

```
find ~/ -type f -name '.lock'
```

Comment: This works for all JetBrains IDE editions, the location of the configuration directory is documented here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory

Comment: thanks so much - a restart would have been so painful in my circumstances

Comment: For me (PopOS) the dir was `~/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate/config/JetBrains` - I lost my previous config, deleted too hastily, you may wish to proceed differently.

Comment: @kcostilow, as this answer said, you should delete the `.lock` file in that directory, not the whole directory. I just did it and lost nothing.

Comment: @kcostilow, I haven't tested the solution on PopOS, but I think you didn't need to delete the entire directory. But only one .lock file

Comment: On MacOS you can run `find . -name '.lock' -delete` from `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains` folder. This worked for me.

Comment: thanks, it's worked, for me it was remove `.lock` file in this folder: `/home/your_username/.config/JetBrains/your_software`, replace `your_username` and `your_software` with actual data, such as `PyCharm2023.2`

Comment: Thanks. Deleting .lock from `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/GoLand2023.2/` worked

Comment: The [path seems to be updated](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory). Look for the system path on the reference link. I found mine in `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/.pid`. Note that the file was NOT `.lock` but `.pid`.

Comment: Installed PyCharm via flatpak in OpenSUSE Aeon (MicroOS), and the directory was located at `~/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Professional/config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2` removing the `.lock` file resolved the error.

Comment: For me it was enough to run command `rm .config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/.lock` from my home directory.

Comment: In My case it was ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2023.2/.lock

Comment: Deleting the `.lock` file actually does work, but before you are able to delete the file in some certain situations, it is hidden. `command + shift + .` will show it on MacOS.

Comment: Confirming deleting ```~/.config/JetBrains/Rider2023.2/.lock``` works on Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 64):

I also faced a similar issue, on a [MacBook Air (M1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air_(Apple_silicon)#Third_generation_(Retina_with_Apple_silicon)).

> Cannot connect to already running IDE instance.
> Exception: Process 427 is still running

I resolved it by running the following command on the terminal.

```
kill -9 427
```

Comment: I faced this for webstorm. Did above as `kill -9 436` then it started working.

Comment: This kills PID that Pycharm _thinks_ it owns because of the lock file. The PID is more than likely not actually an instance of Pycharm at this point, so you might be killing something you don't want to. You should delete the lock file itself. In my case this was `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/.lock`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error:

I resolved it by running the command: `kill -9 2610.` 2610 was the PID. So for your case, it will be `kill -9 464`

The reason is that there could be a process running.

Comment: Yeah my error was process 175 still running. So killing with this command works! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I faced this problem today. I did a `ps -ef | grep 481`  (for me the error was - `Cannot connect to already running IDE instance. Exception: Process 481 is still running`) and it showed [Notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_(Apple)). I closed Notes and then restarted IntelliJ IDEA. It started working.

Answer (score 11):

You can follow the procedures by which I had resolved this issue (on Linux):

1. Go to the *home* directory
2. Then go to the *.config/JetBrains* directory
3. There you can find the IDE's folder you have used with the version. Go to the version's folder you are currently using.
4. Delete the *.lock* file

Try now and the IDE should open.

Comment: this one works `cd .config/JetBrains && find . -iname '*.lock' -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 11):

On macOS here is how I fixed it:

1. open [iTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2)
2. `cd /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/`
3. `find . -name .lock`
4. `rm -rf <lock_file_path>`

Comment: For even faster copy paste: `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/`.
Also the good ol' reboot might help.

Comment: In fact a one-liner: `rm -i ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/*/.lock`. The `-i` flag makes it ask you for each file. That way you can keep those for instances which might actually be running.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it by killing the process with its process ID.

For me it was 511, so I ran this command in [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal) (I am using macOS):

```
kill -9 511
```

Answer (score 6):

I just run into this problem. I am using [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish). When I killed the process shown in the dialog box, it shut down my Firefox browser. Then I managed to open [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) without any issues. I opened up Firefox after that. So far so good.

Answer (score 6):

For Linux users:

1. Execute `ps -ef | grep <port displayed in error message>` to see if it is getting used by any process.
2. `kill -9 <process ID from 1.>`
3. Now try to launch again.

Answer (score 6):

For macOS users on [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2023:
Remove the .lock file from your terminal using

`rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/.lock`

Comment: Mine was similar to this except my path was named PhpStorm2023.

`rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2023.*/.lock`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had an error code of *567*. Killing the process didn't help, so I had to delete the *.lock* file.

In my case lock file was at: */Users/yourUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2023.2/.lock*

I just run the [rm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_(Unix)) command on it to remove the file and [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm) worked.

Answer (score 4):

For me (IntelliJ IDEA installed from Flatpak on [Pop!_OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop!_OS)) the location of .lock file is `~/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community/config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2`. All you need is to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

I just killed the troublesome process (process 516) in my terminal.

```
sudo kill 516   
// '516' <- (Instead of '516') PASTE YOUR PROCESS CODE HERE
```

Answer (score 3):

I got Linux [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro) ([Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)) from [Flatpak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak), and my *.lock* file is at *~/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Professional/config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/.lock*. Deleting that and everything works like mentioned above.

I, by the way, had [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) 2 :S So it is not something I could just kill.

Answer (score 2):

## macOS:

The problem is a **lock file** still existing.
On crashes this may be the case.

The solution is to remove them:

```bash
rm -i ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/*/.lock
```

This will ask you to delete any lock files it finds, for example:

> ```bash
> $ rm -i ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/*/.lock
> remove PyCharm2023.2/.lock? y
> $
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind your path on macOS might be this one:

```
/Users/john-doe//Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, just run the repair. For me, it's in the *bin* folder.

[image]

Comment: Please review  *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77546783/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.